# Example of two non isomorphic universal covers.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, covering-spaces

I know that if a connected and locally path-connected topological space $X$ admits an universal cover, than it's unique up to isomorphism ("isomorphism" is meant in the category of (connected) covering spaces of $X$). Nevertheless,I didn't manage to find in the literature any example of a connected (and not locally path-connected) space which has two non-isomorphic universal covers. Could you help me?

**Important!:** My definition of universal covering is **NOT** a covering map whom domain is simply connected! In fact, I'm studying the topic from [E.H.Spanier, Algebraic Topology](https://ramamishrasite.files.wordpress.com/2019/08/edward-h.-spanier-algebraic-topology-mcgraw-hill-inc-1966.pdf) which gives a broader definition at page 79.

Comment: To begin with, this would require a universal cover that allows an endomorphism (in that category) that is not an isomorphism for whatever reason (not bijective, inverse not continuous). This already seems difficult (and after that you have to factor that endomorphism over some different cover)

Comment: Nothing of substance, simply terminology: You are looking for a connected topological space $X$ such that the category of connected covering spaces of $X$ has (at least) two non-isomorphic [weakly initial objects.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weakly+initial+object)